# ASP.net page navigation with Workflow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, workflow, .net-4.5

I am using `.Net4.5` and `visual studio 2012`. Can someone tell me how to do ASP.net page navigation with `Workflow 4.5` ?

1.) Unable to Create the class :

I have created an Empty MVC project and the i tried R-Clicking on the `Project`, selected `Add-->New Item` but was unable to find the option `-->Worfklow -->Activity`. How can i solve this ?

2.) Any tutorial that walks through this

Answer (score 1):

You should create 2 projects.

The first one will be your ASP.NET MVC project.

The second one will be your Workflow project. Make sure this is an Activity Library project.

Create your activities in your Activity Library project and reference this project in your ASP.NET MVC project.